# почему мой велосипед не работает?

Tags: python, kivy

пишу калькулятор с используя kivy 
даже на гитхаб залил
https://github.com/maqstein/calculator
у меня аллергия на повторение кода по этому решил реализовать через перебор значений в словаре но при запуске подсчете или очищении лейбла программа вылетает. функии по отдельности работают. проблема не в них

```
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 400)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)


class MyApp(App):

    def calculate(self):
        try:
            self.formula = str(eval(self.label.text))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            self.formula="opening a black hole"
            # TODO: open a black hole here
        self.update_label()

    def clear_label(self, instance):
        self.formula = '0'
        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):
        self.label.text = self.formula

    def add_a_thing(self, instance):
        if self.formula == "0":
            self.formula = ""

        self.formula += str(instance.text)
        self.update_label()

    def build(self):

        # some crutch here
        self.label = Label(text='0', font_size=40, halign='right', text_size=(295, 100), size_hint=(1, 0.4))

        self.formula = '0'
        box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        grid_layout = GridLayout(rows=5, cols=4)
        box_layout.add_widget(self.label)

        # magic

        for i in self.operations:
            if not bool(self.operations[i]): # if there is no value in dictionary this will be False(cause of not it will be True)
                grid_layout.add_widget(Button(text=f"{i}",on_press=self.add_a_thing))
            else:
                grid_layout.add_widget(Button(text=f"{i}",on_press=self.operations[i]))

        box_layout.add_widget(grid_layout)
        return box_layout

    operations ={
                '%':'',
                '/':'',
                '*':'',
                '-':'',
                '7':'',
                '8':'',
                '9':'',
                '+':'',
                '4':'',
                '5':'',
                '6':'',
                'Clr':clear_label,
                '1':'',
                '2':'',
                '3':'',
                '=':calculate,
                '':'',
                '0':'',
                '.':'',
                '':'',
                }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

вот ошибка при попытке очищения лейбла

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/maq/PycharmProjects/explorer/main.py", line 82, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 340, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 325, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 231, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1360, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1376, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:/Users/maq/PycharmProjects/explorer/main.py", line 21, in calculate
     self.formula = str(eval(self.label.text))
 AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'label'
```

P.S я знаю про язык разметки kivy,но хочу реализовать свой калькулятор именно таким образом.

Comment: Вам непонятен текст ошибки?

Answer (score 2):

`self.add_a_thing` - связанный метод, ему при вызове автоматически передается `self` в качестве первого аргумента.

`calculete` в `operations` - это просто функция, она ожидает `self`, т.е. MyApp, а получает `instance` типа `Button`.

ООП в `python` довольно своеобразный, объявления внутри класса не имеют отношения ни к одному конкретному экземпляру, только к самому классу, а экземпляры могут их видеть из за иерархического поиска имен как в экземпляре, так и в классе и в его предках.

Короче говоря, что-то относящееся конкретно к экземпляру придется инициализировать внутри метода класса, а методы будут связанными только (почти только) когда явно указывать перед ними переменную экземпляра.

Повторение кода это не хорошо, но явное всегда выглядит лучше неявного, это я о пустых полях в словаре, под которыми подразумевается `add_a_thing`. Поищите компромисс.